# Find differing items in mysql database when another item is the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a SQL database that is holding product information, including the name and description of products.

The way it is currently set up is something like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| products_id | language_id | products_name    | products_description           |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
|           1 |           1 | A19845002        | CONE DRIVE ASSEMBLY            |
|           1 |           2 | A19845002        | CONE DRIVE ASSEMBLY            |
|        4619 |           1 | A51959001        | CONE DRIVE SPACER              |
|        4619 |           2 | A51959001        | CONE DRIVE SPACER              |
|       13600 |           1 | A18535004        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       13600 |           2 | A18535004        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       13701 |           1 | A17236001GEARSET | CONE DRIVE GEARSET             |
|       13701 |           2 | A17236001GEARSET | CONE DRIVE GEARSET             |
|       14388 |           1 | A18535003        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       14388 |           2 | A18535003        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       14389 |           1 | A18535002        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       14389 |           2 | A18535002        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       14390 |           1 | A18535001        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       14390 |           2 | A18535001        | CONE DRIVE UNIT                |
|       14727 |           1 | A19346006        | CONE DRIVE SPEED REDUCER       |
|       14727 |           2 | A19346006        | CONE DRIVE SPEED REDUCER       |
|       14859 |           1 | A18957002        | CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR UNIT      |
|       14859 |           2 | A18957002        | CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR UNIT      |
|       14867 |           1 | 604037           | CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR           |
|       14867 |           2 | 604037           | CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR           |
|       15182 |           1 | A17236001        | CONE DRIVE UNIT SM-502000-AJ   |
|       15182 |           2 | A17236001        | CONE DRIVE UNIT SM-502000-AJ   |
|       15410 |           1 | A19346004        | CONE DRIVE WORM REDUCER        |
|       15410 |           2 | A19346004        | CONE DRIVE WORM REDUCER        |
|       15751 |           1 | 604036           | CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR 2.75 BORE |
|       15751 |           2 | 604036           | CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR 2.75 BORE |
|       15752 |           1 | 604035           | MSR 50 CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR    |
|       15752 |           2 | 604035           | MSR 50 CONE DRIVE GEARMOTOR    |
|       15842 |           1 | A19346005        | CONE DRIVE WORM REDUCER        |
|       15842 |           2 | A19346005        | KEGELRÄDER WORM REDUCER        |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
```

It'd like to go through and find out where `products_description` is DIFFERENT when it is the same `products_id`, but different `language_id`. (1 should be English, 2 should be German). If I ran the query on this, I'd like to have an easy way to find CONE DRIVE WORM REDUCER/KEGELRÄDER WORM REDUCER (so the `product_id` or `product_name`).

How would I go about doing this with mysql? I'm not really used to doing a lot of database stuff, but I need to find if any of these products have been treated properly or not.

Comment: "If I ran the query on this, I don't want any results (because they're all the same)." So, perhaps that's not a very useful example then!

Comment: @Strawberry It's a perfectly useful example; he's looking for IDs of products which have already had their descriptions translated into German where necessary. I'm not sure why that's what he is after, but it doesn't fail to make sense.

Comment: For every result set there is (theoretically) a set of queries capable of providing that result. The more representative the data set, the smaller the set of possible queries. The set of queries capable of returning 0 results is infinite. Ergo, the data set is not useful. ;-)

Comment: Strawberry is definitely right that it's not worded the best, but it is understandable. I had considered making a change, and will do that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products_id
FROM products_table -- assumed
GROUP BY products_description
  HAVING COUNT(products_id) > 1
```

Should give you a result containing product IDs for products which have had their descriptions translated. If you decide you instead want IDs for products which *haven't* had their descriptions translated, replace the `>` test in the `HAVING` clause with an `=`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. There are a whopping 98 products with their names translated.

Comment: @Rob Looks like you've got your work cut out for you. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P1.PRODUCTS_ID, P1.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, P2.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION
FROM PRODUCTS AS P1
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS P2
ON P2.PRODUCTS_ID = P1.PRODUCTS_ID
AND P1.LANGUAGE_ID <> P2.LANGUAGE_ID
AND P1.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION<> P2.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION
```